# MongoDB/Mongoose Update Embeded Array By Element Number

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm novice to MongoDB/Mongoose. I have a bounded array for a user. How would I query for firstName: bob and update pet[0] array?

When reading examples, the query is always on the embeded document array itself, as each element value would be unique in a whole collection. Since this is not the case in my situation, I need to query on the outside document(like firstName) and then update the element by element number.

For example:

```
UserModel.update(
    { firstName: "bob" },
    {'$set':  {'pets.$.
    //not going to work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one

```
UserModel.findOne({ firstName: "bob" }, function(err, user) {
    user.pets[0] = // new pets is here.
    user.save(function(err) {...});
```

Comment: ah...thanks. I didn't know it was simple as that. I thought I had to use `$set`

Comment: @dman, the positional `$` operator if you do not know the position of the element in the array. refer to [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Comment: Would this be slower than just `update()` since it returns the whole document before updating?